# Как в Laravel "зарегистрировать" контейнер для объектов

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-5.7

В общем есть клиенты для подключения к API, для каждого из этих клиентов есть адаптер:

```
<?php
namespace App\Weather\Adapters;

use App\Weather\Clients\ClientOpenWeather;
use App\Weather\Translators\TranslatorOpenWeather;

class ClientOpenWeatherAdapter implements WeatherClientAdapterInterface
{

    private $client;

    public function __construct(ClientOpenWeather $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function getWeather(float $lat,float $lon)
        {
        //Получение данных о погоде от API
        $dataWeather = $this->client->getWeather($lat, $lon);
        if ($dataWeather === null) {
            return null;
        }

        //Трансляция данных из массива в WeatherDTO
        return TranslatorOpenWeather::translate($dataWeather);
    }
}
```

В контроллере я хочу получить доступ к массиву (коллекции, любой другой структуре позволяющий итерировать) объектов адаптеров:
Примерно следующим способом:

```php
foreach($apiAdapters as $apiAdapter){
    $apiAdapter->getWeather($lat, $lon);    
}
```

Проблема заключается в том как "**зарегистрировать**" такой ***контейнер*** данных в laravel. Чтобы в него можно было добавлять новые адаптеры по типу того как добавляются `provides`, `aliases` в `config/app.php`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Возможно есть какое-либо решение данной проблемы так как в данный момент приходиться использовать следующий печальный код:

```
...
 public function addWeather(
    Request $request,
    ClientOpenWeatherAdapter $clientOpenWeatherAdapter,
    ClientYandexWeatherAdapter $clientYandexAdapter
) {
...
$clientOpenWeatherAdapter->getWeather($lat, $lon);
$clientYandexAdapter->getWeather($lat, $lon);
...
}
```

Возможно вопрос слишком тривиальный, но попытки все это реализовать или найти что-то в гугле не привели к успеху.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смог **решить** данную **задачу** следующим образом:

1. был создан конфиг - `config/weather_services.php`

Содержимое weather_services.php:

```
<?php
return [
'YandexWeather' => \App\Weather\Adapters\ClientYandexWeatherAdapter::class,
'OpenWeather' => \App\Weather\Adapters\ClientOpenWeatherAdapter::class,
];
```

2. Для получения доступа (создания) к объектам в *контроллере* использовался *код*

```php
$apiServices = config('weather_services');
foreach ($apiServices as $apiName => $apiClientAdapterClass) {
...
    $weather = app()->make($apiClientAdapterClass)->getWeather($lat, $lon);
...
}
```